# In Spring MVC, does using 'redirect:process' or 'redirect:/process' differ regarding causing a lost session or session value?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, session, redirect

I am experiencing strange behavior in my Spring MVC 3.2 application, and I noticed that this only happening when the redirect is done in an alternate way; so my questions are:

1. Is doing '**redirect:/process**' **any** different from
   '***redirect:process***' for redirecting to an internal controller ?

   Does the added slash make any difference, such as affecting session handling ?
2. What are the reasons for a lost session (or lost session attributes) ?

   There's a value I read through my application; even thou I do redirects in many cases, when I add a **slash** before the Controller URI, **on production** I am sometimes losing this value.

   Any clue on how to troubleshoot the lost session value ?

**Note:** I am using methods `httpRequest.getSession().setAttribute` and `httpSession.getAttribute` for accessing the session.

Comment: Stacktrace ? Error? Code causing the error?

Comment: I get a NullPointerException due to value I'm fetching from the session being null. This happens about a dozen times over the course of the day.

Comment: This happens in a GET controller method, when I return (as the view name) value 'redirect:/process'. Note, I cannot reproduce this locally.

Comment: [Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-redirecting-redirect-prefix):
A logical view name such as `redirect:/myapp/some/resource` will redirect relative to the current Servlet context, while a name such as `redirect:http://myhost.com/some/arbitrary/path` will redirect to an absolute URL.

Comment: In most locations in my code, I am using 'redirect:process' to redirect to another controller in the same application, no backslash, so Spring doesn't really make sense here, especially that adding the backslash is **apparently** causing issues.

Answer (score 1):

with '/' you are declaring a path from root, which is your servlet context path. without '/', usually it's going to a path relative to your current sub path. for example, if you are at '/go/url', your are pointing to '/go/url/next', not '/next'.

I didn't check spring source code but that's how it works in web browser usually.

EDIT:

I'm sorry, in Spring MVC, you must always provide full path, not just relative path. So you should do "redirect:/full/path".

Comment: Right, and I am using a path starting with '/' now, all good. However I didn't see how your answer is relevant regarding lost sessions.

Comment: You probably wanna double check the value you are setting is not null in the first place ...

Answer (score 0):

Just a note: `/` is a slash, backslash is `\`.

Except for external causes because of other errors, neither `redirect:process` not `redirect:/process` should change anything as long as the session is concerned.

But those 2 redirects are **not** supposed to do the same thing, unless you are on the root application page. Assuming that your application runs on HTTP port 80 on server.domain, with a servlet context of myapp, and you are processing a request to `http://server.domain/myapp/local/part`, `redirect:process` would ask browser to request `http://server.domain/myapp/local/part/process`, when `redirect:/process` would ask browser to request `http://server.domain/myapp/process`.

What happens next depends on your controller mappings.

Comment: This is awfully weird then. I receive a response on a controller URI 'http://domain/app/result', but I do 'redirect:process' I am hitting the Controller having RequestMapping 'process' (and not 'result/process'). Based on your description, this shouldn't be possible

Comment: Is the @RequestMapping value for the controller "/process.htm"?  If so, have you tried using "redirect:/process.htm"?

Comment: No, there is no '.htm' suffix, I am reaching my correct controller, but losing sessions, whether I do 'redirect:process' or 'redirect:/proceess' it's the same.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to analyse, what is causing the lost session attributes. One approach would be to implement your own HttpSessionAttributeListener and log in `public void attributeRemoved(HttpSessionBindingEvent event)`  implementation. Also keep spring log level to debug.

Comment: Thanks, however I can't use Debug on production, and this is not yet reproduced locally. So I will implement what you mentioned and see what's happening.